# Полиморфизм и его реализации

Tags: java

Хотелось бы узнать побольше про полиморфизм простыми словами и про его реализации потому что как я понял все везде спорят что нет полиморфизма, а есть только его реализации, про реализации я не очень понял, в смысле реализации?

Вот как я понял различные его реализации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или только вторая картинка это полиморфизм? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае **один и тот же метод**, можно вызывать по разному, с разным количеством параметров 
Это называется перегрузка методов, и да, это полиморфизм
Используется это для того что бы не писать разные функции которые делают одно и тоже, просто с разными типами данных. А что бы использовать одно и тоже имея, для разных параметров (например как ниже для второго случая)
Второй случай, через наследование можно вызывать одну и туже функцию с разными реализациями
Например у тебя есть массив животных (которые наследуются от Animal) и ты хочешь посмотреть у кого какой "звук"
Ты делаешь так

```
Animals[] animals = {new Cat(), new Dog(), new Cow(), new Cow(), new Dog()} 
for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++)  
    animals[i].voise()
```

И получается что из за разных реализаций в разных классах наследниках, ты будешь получать разные результат, а вызываешь ты один и тот же метод в коде
Иначе тебе бы тебе пришлось для каждого животного писать разные имена методов, и как то определять класс, вызывать подходящий метод этого класса и.т.д.

Comment: То есть это 2 реализации полиморфизма? Можно сказать что перегрузка методов это полиморфизм и что переопределение методов это тоже полиморфизм?

Comment: Можно и так сказать. Это немного сложнее, но суть я думаю вы уловили.
Если очень кратко, то, полиморфизм - это разные реализации одного и того же метода

Comment: Почему у вас написано 2 раза new Dog() и 2 раза new Cow()?

Comment: Почему бы и нет, просто для количества т.к. это разные объекты будут

Answer (score 0):

И переопределение и перегрузка методов - это проявления полиморфизма. Только переопределение - это проявление полиморфизма подтипов (истинный полиморфизм), а перегрузка - это проявление ad-hoc-полиморфизма (мнимый полиморфизм).